# How to fix remote access error in PLEX Media Server?

Tags: plex

Basically I have a LAN connection through my WIFI router and unfortunately my computer does not have WIFI privileges and so it is connected to the internet through cable line (coming from the router). Now I created a new account in PLEX media server and wanted access my contents remotely. But I failed to do so.[image: My ip configuration is as shown in the picture.]

My ip configuration is as shown in the picture. Is there anything I have to modify ? And I want make clear that from the router only my PC is connected via cable and nothing is connected, also I do not have any modem. I use my mobile under the wifi router. My router is from D-Link and I have UpnP enabled.
I have tried almost every possible way that are given in the internet but failed to make any difference. Also I want to say that I am a quite novice in such router configuration thing.

Thanks in advance for your time.

EDIT 1: In accordance to the solution given by **jcbermu** i would like to show my router configuration page:[image]
Which option should I modify ?

EDIT 2: Adding this picture to get some help for router configuration. [image]

Comment: Where is your plex media server located? If it on your local network and you want to access it remotely you need to open the appropriate ports in your router.

Comment: What is the model of your dlink router?

Comment: D-Link DIR 816 @DavidPostill

Comment: [How to Forward Ports in a D-Link DIR-816 Router](https://portforward.com/d-link/dir-816/) and open port 32400.

Comment: pretty useful link. But I am stuck at the PROTOCOL option. Which option should I choose TCP or UDP ? @DavidPostill

Comment: [Both](https://portforward.com/ports.htm) and search for Plex.

Comment: actually you can select only one option, no place for choosing both.

Comment: So you add two rules. One for TCP and one for UDP.

Comment: not helpful, it says that the port is already taken when i set one rule and try to set the other rule @DavidPostill

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong or your router is broken.

Comment: @HirenGarai TCP is the choice for Plex Server

Comment: ok, so I set up again newly and for few seconds PLEX shows I have remote access but then again the error message pops up. I kept retrying but no difference. i don't understand where I am doing wrong.

Comment: so what should I do right now ?

Answer (score 1):

Your Plex Server is running in port 32400.
If you are trying to connect remotely from outside your network, you have to follow these steps:

The internet router is doing NAT (*translating a single public IP address to the private IP addresses in your network*) as in the following image:

[image]

1. It's necessary to open the port TCP 32400 in the router and redirect all the traffic coming to that port to the IP address of the server.

Your router should have a menu like this:

[image]

Where you indicate the port and the IP address of the server

2. go to the Plex Server configuration and find this where you can test that the server is reachable from outside
   [image]

Comment: thanks again for your time, i have edited my question a little bit by adding the configuration page, will please guide from there. Thank you @jcbermu

Comment: @HirenGarai `User defined service name`: **Plex**, `Protocol`: **TCP**, `WAN Port`: **32400**, `LAN Port`: **32400**, `LAN Ip Address`: **192.168.0.4**

Comment: yes, I have done the exact same way you said, but no difference, it still says I have no remote access.@jcbermu

Comment: Do I have to enable port triggering ? @jcbermu

Comment: I have disabled upnp and then retried but no improvement.

Comment: @Hiren Go to [https://www.whatismyip.com/](https://www.whatismyip.com/) and get your public IP address, then go [here](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/), put the **public** IP address and the port and test. If it fails the problem is the router configuration

Comment: yes, it said that the port is closed on my ip address. So my router's configuration is wrong. Any suggestion for doing it right ? @jcbermu

Comment: @HirenGarai Please, update the router menu picture in your question with the actual state

Comment: I have added one picture, is it helpful ? or I have to upload more ? @jcbermu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83110/discussion-between-jcbermu-and-hiren-garai).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83116/discussion-between-hiren-garai-and-jcbermu).